# Multiple messages for single JSF Validator

Tags: validation, jsf

I have run into a blocking scenario and need help. The problem is basically this:
  There is a field on the page which is attached to a validator. This validator in turn validates other fields in particular relation and should throw error messages for all the related fields that have failed validation.

So basically I want a single validator exception to contain multiple facesmessage which should be displayed on the page a list. Is there any method to do the same. From my understanding each ValidatorException can be attached with a single FacesMessage. So I tried out by giving "\n" and even "" in between different messages in a single FacesMessage string to display the messages in new lines but it does not work. Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about adding the faces messages directly, for example if you had 3 text input fields you wanted to display a message on, and had them bound as input1, input2 and input3:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
    input1.getClientId(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()),
    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, 
        "Validation Failed", "Validation Failed"));

FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
    input2.getClientId(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()),
    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, 
        "Validation Failed", "Validation Failed"));

FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
    input3.getClientId(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()),
    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, 
        "Validation Failed", "Validation Failed"));
```

Comment: I have not tried out it yet but I am concerned will this approach reflect these messages along with the other validator messages. I tried something like this by including similar methods in the submit method. But then the validation occured at a different lifecycle stage and all the messages did not get out put at once. I mean if i got validator 1 associated with message 1 validator 2 associated with message 2 and above function adding message 3 and message 4..after validation 1st and 2nd message would come together or else messages 3 & 4 will be displayed. Hope I'm clear..

Comment: When we encounter this in our projects, we don't put any validators on the page, but handle it all from a submit method on the bean.  That's really the cleanest way we've found.

Comment: @Nicholas

I was needlessly worried. The method you said is working fine for displaying multiple validation messages for a single field.